# My splash screen doesn't show animation and stop without open next screen (fragment)

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, splash-screen, android-fragmentactivity

I first created my onboarding fragment and then made my animated splash screen.However, when I run my application my splash screen does not show the animate and stop with out open the next fragment

this is my splash screen code

```
'''
```

class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivitySplashBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    supportActionBar?.hide()


    binding = ActivitySplashBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.motionLayout.setTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
        override fun onTransitionStarted(
            motionLayout: MotionLayout?,
            startId: Int,
            endId: Int
        ) {

        }

        override fun onTransitionChange(
            motionLayout: MotionLayout?,
            startId: Int,
            endId: Int,
            progress: Float
        ) {

        }

        override fun onTransitionCompleted(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, currentId: Int) {
            val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

        override fun onTransitionTrigger(
            motionLayout: MotionLayout?,
            triggerId: Int,
            positive: Boolean,
            progress: Float
        ) {

        }

    })
```

'''

my splash scene for MotionsLayout

'''

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:duration="1000"
    motion:autoTransition="jumpToStart">
   <KeyFrameSet>
       <KeyAttribute
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView8" />
       <KeyAttribute
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView8"
           motion:framePosition="0"
           android:scaleX="1.2" />
       <KeyAttribute
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView8"
           motion:framePosition="0"
           android:scaleY="1.2" />
       <KeyAttribute
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView8"
           motion:framePosition="20"
           android:scaleX="0.7" />
       <KeyAttribute
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView8"
           motion:framePosition="20"
           android:scaleY="0.7" />
       <KeyAttribute
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView8"
           motion:framePosition="40"
           android:scaleX="0.7" />
       <KeyAttribute
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView8"
           motion:framePosition="40"
           android:scaleY="0.7" />
       <KeyAttribute
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView8"
           motion:framePosition="100"
           android:scaleX="50.0" />
       <KeyAttribute
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView8"
           motion:framePosition="100"
           android:scaleY="50.0" />
   </KeyFrameSet>
    <OnClick motion:targetId="@+id/imageView8" />
</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:layout_height="287dp"
        android:layout_width="313dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView7"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.487"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp" />
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        motion:layout_editor_absoluteY="293dp"
        android:layout_height="335dp"
        android:layout_width="303dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</ConstraintSet>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Do You add MotionScene in your MotionLayout in the xml File ?

I think the problem with the MotionScene that control the animation and transaction time

you can try this steps >> Create xml folder inside res then add activity_main_scene.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="5000"
        motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd">
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyCycle
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/moon"
                motion:framePosition="0"
                motion:wavePeriod="2"
                motion:waveShape="sawtooth"
                android:rotation="180"
                motion:waveOffset="0" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

then in your layout in splash xml file add the MotionScene like

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">
```

Comment: I already had this xml file for splash scene